# Display empty field in lwc datatable if user not entered value. Empty field should not effect other fields displaying in table

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

MMID AND STOCKING ID are fields which are optional.
If these fields are empty it effecting other fields to display. Entire table not displaying. Because its checking the values.

```js
@wire(getSelectedCaseLineItems, {caseid: '$recordId'})
caseLineItems({ error, data }){
    if(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
        this.caseLineItems = data.map(
            record => Object.assign(
                {
                    "Sold_To__r.Name": record.Sold_To__r.Name, 
                    "Ship_To__r.Name": record.Ship_To__r.Name,
                    "MMID__r.Name": record.MMID__r.Name == null ? "": record.MMID__r.Name, 
                    "Stocking_ID__r.Name": record.Stocking_ID__r.Name == null ? "" : record.Stocking_ID__r.Name
                },
                record
            ) 
        );
    }
    else if(error){
        this.error = error;
        this.caseLineItems = undefined;
    }
}
```

----------------------------------IF-ELSE CONDITION-----------------------

```js
@wire(getSelectedCaseLineItems, {caseid: '$recordId'})
caseLineItems({ error, data }){     // 58789    58799
    if(data)
    {
        console.log(data);

        if(data.MMID__r.Name != null && data.Stocking_ID__r.Name != null){
            this.caseLineItems = data.map(
                record => Object.assign(
                    {
                        "Sold_To__r.Name": record.Sold_To__r.Name,
                        "Ship_To__r.Name": record.Ship_To__r.Name,
                        "MMID__r.Name": record.MMID__r.Name, "Stocking_ID__r.Name": record.Stocking_ID__r.Name
                    },
                    record
                ) 
            );
        } else {
            this.caseLineItems = data.map(
                record => Object.assign(
                    {
                        "Sold_To__r.Name": record.Sold_To__r.Name,
                        "Ship_To__r.Name": record.Ship_To__r.Name,
                        // "MMID__r.Name": record.MMID__r.Name == null ? "": record.MMID__r.Name, 
                        // "Stocking_ID__r.Name": record.Stocking_ID__r.Name == null ? "" : record.Stocking_ID__r.Name
                    },
                    record
                ) 
            );
        }
    }
    else if(error){
        this.error = error;
        this.caseLineItems = undefined;
    }
}
```

------If i use if else condition getting error. That Name is undefined(which is in IF-CONDITION)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code like this:

```
this.caseLineItems = data.map(
          record => Object.assign(
              {"Sold_To__r.Name": record.Sold_To__r?.Name ?? '', "Ship_To__r.Name": record.Ship_To__r?.Name ?? '',
                "MMID__r.Name": record.MMID__r?.Name ?? '', "Stocking_ID__r.Name": record.Stocking_ID__r?.Name ?? ''
               },
              record
          ) 
       );
```

You can youse the ? operator to check if exists the object containing the field, and then if the field is undefined or null just set an empty string.

In your case, your field is not null but undefined as it does not come as part of the object.

Hope it helps.